# Exporting web in sharepoint solution gallery issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, migration

I am exporting web via SPExport Api of Microsoft and it works fine but I think it does not export solution gallery. Please tell me is there any work around for this problem. I am using this code for export `exportSettings` has all the settings set for export.

```
export = new SPExport(exportSettings);
export.Completed += new EventHandler<SPDeploymentEventArgs>(export_Completed);
export.ProgressUpdated += new EventHandler<SPDeploymentEventArgs>(export_ProgressUpdated);
export.Run();
strExportChangeToken = exportSettings.CurrentChangeToken;
```